# Show when a new 2 month high has been reached

Tags: pine-script

I am a bloody beginner at Pine and would like to realize my first programming idea. Unfortunately I am totally overwhelmed how I can realize this technically.

It should be simply only indicated to me if a share has reached a new 2 month high. How can I realize this?

Comment: Usually, you read a book about about a topic you don't know yet. Later on, look at tutorials, play with existing examples, try-and-error your own code.

Comment: I've read the Pine User Manual but I simply didn't find a way to translate this particular task into code. Maybe I can work with max(). Then I would have to compare X days in a loop. But there would be the problem how many trading days the last two months had.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
twoMonthHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "2M", high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(twoMonthHigh)
plotshape(close > twoMonthHigh, "twoMonthHigh", shape.triangleup, location.abovebar)
```